# How to modify function input parameters without specifying type?

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, interface

I'm trying to make a function that accept 2 parameters, and set value of second parameter to first one, it might looks like(I'm not sure):

```golang
func set(a interface{}, b interface{}) {
  // do something to make a = b
}
```

it works like this:

```golang
a := 0
b := 10
set(&a, b)
// here a should be 10

s1 := ""
s2 := "what"
set(&s1, s2)
// here s1 should be "what"
```

it is expected to work on all basic types, like ints, floats, strings, bool, ...

How can I acheive this?

Comment: Golang does not support generics, so this isn't something that you should try to be doing with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using reflection:

```
func set(a interface{}, b interface{}) {
    reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(b))
}
```

Note that this code does not check whether `a` is a pointer and its element type matches the type of the value in `b`. Also note that using reflection is slower and you lose compile-time type safety. The above code is much slower than assigning a single `int` value to an `int` variable or assigning a `string` value to a `string` variable.

Testing it:

```
a := 0
b := 10
set(&a, b)
fmt.Println(a)

s1 := ""
s2 := "what"
set(&s1, s2)
fmt.Println(s1)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/J9z3E8Law9k)):

```
10
what
```

Here's a version that adds checks to avoid runtime panics:

```
func set(a interface{}, b interface{}) error {
    v1 := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    if v1.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return errors.New("a must be pointer")
    }
    if v1.IsZero() {
        return errors.New("a must not be a nil pointer")
    }

    v1 = v1.Elem()
    v2 := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    if v1.Type() != v2.Type() {
        return errors.New("a's element type must match b's type")
    }

    if !v1.CanSet() {
        return errors.New("unsettable value in a")
    }

    v1.Set(v2)
    return nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
a := 0
b := 10
err := set(a, b)
fmt.Printf("set(a, b): a=%v, err: %v\n", a, err)
err = set(&a, b)
fmt.Printf("set(&a, b): a=%v, err: %v\n", a, err)
err = set((*int)(nil), b)
fmt.Printf("set((*int)(nil), b): a=%v, err: %v\n", a, err)

s1 := ""
s2 := "what"
err = set(&s1, s2)
fmt.Printf("set(&s1, s2): s1=%v, err: %v\n", s1, err)
err = set(&s1, b)
fmt.Printf("set(&s1, s2): s1=%v, err: %v\n", s1, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nTYrkh96rDn)):

```
set(a, b): a=0, err: a must be pointer
set(&a, b): a=10, err: <nil>
set((*int)(nil), b): a=10, err: a must not be a nil pointer
set(&s1, s2): s1=what, err: <nil>
set(&s1, s2): s1=what, err: a's element type must match b's type
```

Comment: if I call `set(a, b)` while both a and b are int, it will panic instead of report a compiling error, it makes me worry. Is there any way to avoid runtime error?

Comment: @forrestJiang Added a version that checks the types, and does not panic but returns an `error` if `set()` cannot be performed.

Comment: Although it won't fail at compiling time, but it does avoid panics. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @forrestJiang You cannot create a generic `set()` that fails at compile time. That would require generics which Go does not yet support.